# Internet connection in Nougat

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, job-scheduling, internet-connection

I want to check internet connection in my application but this code doesnt work on android nougat for check internet connection
this code works on marshmallow and kitkat but doesnt work on nougat
please help me

broadcast code:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo=connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        Toast.makeText(context, "connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
}
```

manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="clicksite.org.testinternetconnection">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Just doesn't work? No errors?

Comment: yes.no error.just doesnt work.but works on lower api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same issue. i am thinking of creating a service which runs in background and waits for the broadcast patiently.

I actually nailed it with Task Scheduler us android evernote [here](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) job library then

```
public static void scheduleAdvancedJob() {
    PersistableBundleCompat extras = new PersistableBundleCompat();
    extras.putString("key", "smj");

    int jobId = new JobRequest.Builder(MainConstant.TAG)
            .setExecutionWindow(3_000L, 30_000L)
            .setBackoffCriteria(5_000L, JobRequest.BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setExtras(extras)
            .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .build()
            .schedule();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently adding Broadcast Receivers to the Manifest has been depreciated.

Android docs give this explanation:

> Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive
>   CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they declare the broadcast receiver
>   in their manifest. Apps will still receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
>   broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with
>   Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid.

See if that fixes you issue.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
this.registerReceiver(new NetworkConnectionReceiver(), intentFilter);
```

This might also be of interest:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)

Comment: so how I can get my chats message from server when I connect to Internet ?

Comment: Intent filter works when I open  application ,but I want get message from server when I connect to internet without opening app

Comment: @General455 :: in your original post you say nothing of messaging--only notification of change in connectivity. I do not know which messaging service you are using. I would need more information on that.

Comment: its not important ,I just want when Im out of app when I connect to internet toast for me "you connected...".its ok in api lower than 24 but doesnt work on android nougat

Comment: @General455  :: If you feel my post answered your question, please consider accepting it. Thank you.

Comment: no it is not, because it works just when Im in application, but I need it every time even application is close

Comment: @General455  :: 
 
I can't change the fact that Android has changed their policy. This is fact that the old method does not work with Nougat. They have made these changes for a reason.

Comment: I know this my friend.thank you for your help,but there is no way to solve this?even whit broadcast and job sheduler?

Comment: @General455 :: In your original post you say nothing about  checking internet connection while your app is in the background nor do you mention messaging. You simply stated that your present technique no longer work for Nougat--my answer helps regain that functionality--just not when your app is in the background. Android does not want app to do this for a reason!! And for a messaging app it is not necessary--I know this because I have an app that incorporates messaging and my app users receive messages even while my app is not running. I have answered your question as you stated it.

Comment: Its fantastic man!! just tell me how you get message when app is not open, and how you check internet connection in your app to show notification.please

Comment: @General455 :: As I stated earlier, in order to help you with that I really need to know more about how you are getting your messages, now. What backend service you are using. The messaging issue you are having is worthy of separate Question on SO. Describe the code you have, explain the issue you are having with Nougat. Post a new Question and I will take a look. Make certain that you mention Messaging and many more developers will be looking at your post.

Comment: I use soket io and nodejs for my app

Comment: So you are not using anything like "Pushy" or "Firebase Cloud Messaging"? There are quite a few more messaging providers that are free and they push notifications to you android (and iOS devices)--even while your app is not running. If security is a concern you can incorporate encryption.   It appears you are using a constant (live) connection to your backend server. That strategy will significantly increase data and battery usage.